# How to index a field with mongodb-erlang

Tags: mongodb, indexing, erlang

I want to index a field using mongodb-erlang (https://github.com/comtihon/mongodb-erlang). The sample code works in shell but crashed when i called from code. Anyone have an idea about this issue? I'm using mongo 2.6.5

```
mongo:ensure_index(DBConn, conversations, {key, {page_id, 1}, unique, true, dropDups, true})
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code! And make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I updated the code and mongo version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used mongodb-erlang for more than one year, and the sample code is as follows:

```
Index_spec = [{key,{column_a,1},unique,true,sparse,true}
                          ],
X = collection_a,
 ok = mongo:ensure_index(Connection,X,Index_spec),
```

Comment: I tried your code before and I didn't work also. What is your current mongo version? I think the issue may related to older version. I'm using mongo 2.6.5

Comment: I think the problem may be related your mongo-erlang version.

Comment: In this version, the ensure_index bug has been solved. Commit: 5c52ec779b4f58d8f833bd4b800405779fd15d04 [5c52ec7]
Parents: 02bd61f27c
Author: Valery Tikhonov <com.tihon@mail.ru>
Date: September 5, 2014 at 9:21:24 AM GMT+8

updated readme

Comment: I tried mongodb 2.6.10 and 3.0.3 but unable to make them work as expected. Do you have any idea or example code in production?

Comment: I have faced index problem before and debug it through source code for print log. this is my version of mongodb-erlang "https://github.com/chenyu468/mongodb-erlang.git" , including debug information, please read it and for debug.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated mongodb and mongo-erlang dependency and now it works perfectly. Btw, does ensure_index run on foreground? because i saw thread is blocked on the first time that ensure_index running

Comment: mongodb-erlang application just mapping ensure_index statement to mongo's client protocol's ensure_index statement. From this, you can say it running foreground.